# Vim split screen opens blank split

Tags: split

I am trying to open a different file at some different location while i am working on a file in vim using split screen feature using

vsp:cd.. / folder/filename

after I hit enter it just shows me blank screen with split window.

So I need to know how to open a file in different location from current vim screen[image]

Comment: You can't combine vsp and cd like that. First cd to the directory you want, then vsp with the filename you want. By combining them, I think you've created a new file named 'cd' in '../http/http_protocol'.

Answer (score 3):

So you should actually use:

```
:vsp ../folder/filename
```

No need to use `cd` because `:vsp`  only expects a path not a shell command.